# Django continually checking database for new information

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, performance

So, I was running some ideas through my head for a new website to build, and I am going to need something that would continually checks for new information. I looked around the internet and didn't find any django packages that would help me out. What I would do right now is...

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {timerFunc()}, delay);
function timerFunc() {
    //ajax here to check for new stuff...
}
```

For some reason, I have this notion that it should be possible to have the server-side alert the client side if there is new information but I have no particular reason to believe that. So, my questions are if there is a better way to do this, and if the code I have written is bad practice?

Comment: What you're looking for is a websocket package, there are some out there for Django. Whether your current method is bad practice really depends on how often you check. If you can check, say, once or twice per minute, it's perfectly fine. If you need real-time updates, a websocket is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Websockets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) I believe. They allow the server to send events to the client, instead of polling the server from the client (which is what you are suggesting here).

I may be wrong here, but it looks like there isn't many Django Websocket libraries out there, I have heard about https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon but have never used it.

I *think* (again I could be wrong here) that you may want to use another web framework if you want to use Websockets, I know Flask seems pretty compatible with them http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent.